# Open terminal from keyboard in 23.10

Tags: command-line

Previously `Ctrl + Alt + T` would open a terminal, but in 23.10 this seems to open a search function that closes before you can use it! How do I open a terminal in 23.10 without using a gui at all?

Comment: left windows key and begin to type terminal? Also check `Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Launchers > Launch Terminal` to see what is set. I see no such change in my 23.10 instance using `Wayland` Windowing System

Answer (score -1):

Press Alt+F2.

In the Run a Command window, type gnome-terminal.

Or as suggested change your keyboards shortcuts.